# Maximum upload size in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I understand that I can add the following to the web.config file:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10096" executionTimeout="120"/>
```

This will increase the upload limit for the application.  The problem is that the WEB.CONFIG file is part of the application and part of my installation.  I have multiple customers with different values they want to use.  The Web.config file is overwritten each time they install a new version of my application.  Thus, this would overwrite any modifications to the upload size they might have made.

Currently I have my customers change the Machine.Config file, but this is really not the best solution as they are changing the parameters for the whole IIS Server.

I figured maybe I could have the customer add an App.Config to the folder, where they could set their own parameters.  Since that file is not part of my installation, it would stay.

Has anyone else had this problem, figured out a way to work around having the customer have an ability to have their own custom config file that will not get overwritten when they install a new version of the application?

Thanks,
Cory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In web.config:

```
<httpRuntime configSource="httpRuntime.config"/>
```

In httpRuntime.config:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10096" executionTimeout="120"/>
```

See the configSource attribute in [General Attributes Inherited by Section Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228167%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [SectionInformation.ConfigSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on MSDN for an explanation.